# Can someone explain this 'double negative' trick?

Tags: javascript, html

I am by no means an expert at Javascript, but I have been reading Mark Pilgrim's ["Dive into HTML5"](http://diveintohtml5.info/) webpage and he mentioned something that I would like a better understanding of.

He states:

> Finally, you use the double-negative trick to force the result to a Boolean value (true or false).

```
function supports_canvas() {
  return !!document.createElement('canvas').getContext;
}
```

If anyone can explain this a little better I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 259, accepted):

A logical NOT operator `!` converts a value to a boolean that is the opposite of its logical value.

The second `!` converts the previous boolean result back to the boolean representation of  its original logical value.

[From these docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) for the Logical NOT operator:

> Returns false if its single operand can be converted to true; otherwise, returns true.

So if `getContext` gives you a "falsey" value, the `!!`  will make it return the boolean value `false`. Otherwise it will return `true`.

The "falsey" values are:

- `false`
- `NaN`
- `undefined`
- `null`
- `""` (empty string)
- `0`

Comment: @Grinn : user113716 did not list all. He forgot -0 . I do not mean a unary minus with a zero, but the result of that which is a seperate value. You can create it, for instance,  by assigning -0 to a variable.

Comment: @MarcodeWit: They're equal values in JavaScript. `-0 === 0 // true` user113716 didn't miss anything relevant to the question.

Comment: @squint: First of all user113716 tried to reproduce the list of falsey values and I still think -0 is missing from it. I think it is relevant to the question to be there because maybe someone could think that if 0 is false then -0 becomes true again because of the minus. -0 === 0 only evaluates to true because it is defined that way, not because of being equal values of the same type. Also, if they were really equal then 1/0 should give the same result as 1/-0.

Comment: @MarcodeWit: A user may think that, but there's no reason to. This question is about logic ops, and `0` is always falsey. That's what his answer states.  `-0 === 0` shows they *are* equal values of the same type *because* that's how it's defined. Your division example is a very specific circumstance that has nothing to do with this question or 99.999% of the uses of the `0` value. Heck, even `.toString()` represents them the same way. `(-0).toString(); // "0"`

Comment: `Object.is(0, -0)` returns `false`, so they are not the same thing.

Answer (score 33):

Javascript has a confusing set of rules for what is considered "true" and "false" when placed in a context where a Boolean is expected.  But the logical-NOT operator, `!`, always produces a proper Boolean value (one of the constants `true` and `false`).  By chaining two of them, the idiom `!!expression` produces a proper Boolean with the same truthiness as the original expression.

Why would you bother?  Because it makes functions like the one you show more predictable.  If it didn't have the double negative in there, it might return `undefined`, a `Function` object, or something not entirely unlike a `Function` object.  If the caller of this function does something weird with the return value, the overall code might misbehave ("weird" here means "anything but an operation that enforces Boolean context").  The double-negative idiom prevents this.

Comment: It's not a "confusing" set of rules.

Comment: @Abody97 The list (helpfully shown above) is neither as short as possible (`false`; anything else requires an explicit comparison operator), nor as long as possible (add `{}` and `[]`, at least).  So you have to memorize the list rather than a rule.  That's what I call a confusing language feature.

Comment: Certainly: it's a list, not a rule. I think it's highly subjective whether it's confusing or not. I personally find it highly intuitive to know what's "falsey" and what's "truthy" when cast to a Boolean.

Comment: In any case, I didn't mean to aggressively disagree.

Answer (score 14):

In javascript, using the "bang" operator (!) will return true if the given value is true, 1, not null, etc. It will return false if the value is undefined, null, 0, or an empty string.

So the bang operator will always return a boolean value, but it will represent the opposite value of what you began with. If you take the result of that operation and "bang" it again, you can reverse it again, but still end up with a boolean (and not undefined, null, etc).

Using the bang twice will take a value that could have been undefined, null, etc, and make it just plain `false`. It will take a value that could have been 1, "true", etc. and make it just plain `true`.

The code could have been written:

```
var context = document.createElement('canvas').getContext;
var contextDoesNotExist = !context;
var contextExists = !contextDoesNotExist;
return contextExists;
```

Answer (score 11):

Using !!variable gives you a guarantee of typecast to boolean.

To give you a simple example:

```
"" == false (is true)
"" === false (is false)

!!"" == false (is true)
!!"" === false (is true)
```

But it doesn't make sense to use if you are doing something like:

```
var a = ""; // or a = null; or a = undefined ...
if(!!a){
...
```

The if will cast it to boolean so there is no need to make the implicit double negative cast.

Answer (score 7):

`!` casts "something"/"anything" to a `boolean`.

`!!` gives the original boolean value back (and guarantees the expression is a boolean now, regardless to what is was before)

Answer (score 6):

The first `!` coerces the variable to a boolean type and inverts it. The second `!` inverts it again (giving you the original (correct) boolean value for whatever you are checking).

For clarity you would be better off using

```
return Boolean(....);
```

Comment: `Boolean()` creates a boxed boolean, which does not behave the same as the primitive booleans created by `!!` (for instance, `typeof` will report `"object"`).  Thus, `!!` is preferred.

Comment: To make it return primitive boolean: `return (new Boolean(...)).valueOf()`

Comment: @Zack It doesn't for me. It only does when combined with `new`.

Comment: @alex I'm probably out of date.  That certainly used to do as I described ... about six years ago, when JS interpreters were much less sophisticated.  Also, the current behavior may be browser dependent.

Comment: I know that this is a bit of a stale thread, but I think its important to point out that bang-bang(!!) is far more performant than Boolean(val). http://jsperf.com/bang-bang-vs-boolean

Comment: This is now a very old thread, but in case anyone comes across this while researching performance of the bang(!!) approach vs the Boolean(val) approach as I did, the previous comment by Mad Man Moon no longer appears to be true. [jsperf.com/bang-bang-vs-boolean](https://jsperf.com/bang-bang-vs-boolean) now shows the Boolean(val) approach to be faster in both Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

`document.createElement('canvas').getContext` may evaluate to either `undefined` or an object reference. `!undefined` yields `true`, `![some_object]` yields `false`. This is almost what we need, just inverted. So `!!` serves to convert `undefined` to `false` and an object reference to `true`.

Answer (score 3):

It's to do with JavaScript's weak typing.  `document.createElement('canvas').getContext` is a function object.  By prepending a single `!` it evaluates it as a boolean expression and flips the answer around.  By prepending another `!`, it flips the answer back.  The end result is that the function evaluates it as a boolean expression, but returns an actual boolean result rather than the function object itself.  Prepending `!!` is a quick and dirty way to typecast an expression to a boolean type.

Answer (score 2):

If `document.createElement('canvas').getContext` isn't `undefined` or `null`, it will return `true`. Otherwise it will return `false`.