# getting the first line of text in an element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an example element like this:

```
<div id="element">
  Blah blah blah.
  <div>Header</div>
  ...
</div>
```

it can also look like this:

```
<div id="element">
  <span>Blah blah blah.</span>
  <h4>Header</h4>
  ...
</div>
```

I want to get the first line (defining line loosely) (Blah blah blah.) of text inside the element. It might be wrapped inside a child element or just be naked textnode. How do I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the [`contents()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) method to get all children, including text nodes, filter out any empty (or whitespace only) nodes, then grab the first of the set.

```
var first_line = $("#element")
                       .contents()
                       .filter(function() { 
                           return !!$.trim( this.innerHTML || this.data ); 
                       })
                       .first();
```

*text node:* http://jsfiddle.net/Yftnh/

*element:* http://jsfiddle.net/Yftnh/1/

Comment: thanks, though for me this returns an object rather than text, should I just first_line[0]?

Comment: Yes, this gives you a jQuery object with either the element or the text node. If you want the text content, use `first_line.text()`. If you want to trim away leading and trailing whitespace, do `$.trim( first_line.text() )`.

Comment: Hi can you explain why you do return !!? What is !!?

Comment: It converts to the value's boolean equivalent. After trimming, if `.innerHTML` or `.data` returns an empty string, `!!` will convert it to boolean `false`, because an empty string is considered a "falsey" value. Any non-empty string will result in `true`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686583/can-someone-explain-this-double-negative-trick/4686608#4686608

Comment: +1 from me, but the performance-wary might want to consider using `$.each()` rather than `filter()`.  It's a bit late in the day for me, but an example of this is http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/Yftnh/3/ (ignore revision 2, I'm half asleep here!)

Comment: @Andy E do you have a link or something that explains the significance of filter vs each for performance?

Comment: @Andy E: Nice one. Great use of the comma operator too. @Harry: It just lets you stop the loop once you've found a non-empty node. With `.filter()` you have to let the loop run for each element that `.contents()` returns.

Comment: @Harry: pretty much what @patrick_dw said.  If the contents of the element turns out to be 200 nodes, the `filter()` function runs on each one of those nodes.  `each()` can be broken so that it stops running after it finds what you're looking for.

Comment: @Andy E: For fun, here's one sans comma `return !$.trim((first_line = this).innerHTML||this.data);` :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is idea for you. Of course if there is h4 element before line you want to get:

```
var content = $('#element').html();
var arr = content.split('<h4>');
console.log(arr[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var myElement = $("#element");
while(myElement.children().length > 0)
{
   myElement = myElement.children().first();
}
var firstText = myElement.text();
```

Assuming that the text is correctly wrapped inside an element, of course. You might check whether there's text before the first element:

```
/\s*</.test(myElement.html())
```

Comment: Doesn't work for the first case I believe, that'll match the Header rather than the blah blah blah (maybe should've picked better example text lol)

Comment: If you get <div id="element"><span></span>mytext</div> it gets pretty difficult. You need something recursively traveling through the DOM i guess. How bulletproof does it have to be?

Answer (score 1):

first get the content of the element

```
var content = $('#element').html();
```

then split the text into an array using line break

```
tmp = content.split("\n");
```

the first part of the array is the first line of the element

```
var firstLine = tmp[0];
```

Comment: I first thought, what linebreak, but I see in Fx at least there is. It is however dangerous to rely on. Here is the first line: `alert($("#element").text().split(/\n/)[1])` the [0]th is an empty string... http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/QquSp/

Answer (score 1):

the counter starts at 1

```
myElement.text().split('\n')[1]
```