# Replace last line in Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can easily get the last line in a div by using;

```
 var last_line = $canvas
                       .contents()
                       .filter(function () {
                           return !!$.trim(this.innerHTML || this.data);
                       })
                       .last();
alert(last_line.text());
```

Now I want to replace the last line only.  The text within the div will become quite lengthy over time and I don't want to replace the whole div contents each time, just the last line.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's `replaceWith` function:

```
var last_line = $canvas
                       .contents()
                       .filter(function () {
                           return !!$.trim(this.innerHTML || this.data);
                       })
                       .last().replaceWith('<tag>Content to replace it with</tag>');
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381012/getting-the-first-line-of-text-in-an-element-jquery