# Use :first-line pseudo-element as a jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, pseudo-element

I know I can use CSS `:first-line` pseudo-elmenent to target and change style of the first line in any block of text (like in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6H8sy/). So the first line *can* be found and targeted.

I was wondering if there's any way to actually *select* that text to reuse. Something like `$(':first-line')` (which doesn't work as it is).

Comment: CSS pseudo-selectors are not technically part of the DOM, and therefore cannot be manipulated by JavaScript.

Comment: Akin to highlighting with your mouse?

Comment: @Johnston not really, rather to select a node for later reuse

Comment: @Blazemonger this can be done to retreive content of `:before` pseudo-element (e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/6H8sy/1/) I understand it's still not part of the DOM but was hoping for something similar

Comment: One way would be to take the entire content and place it in a hidden div that is the same width padding and margin as the original div, then remove words until the div's height is the height of 1 line. At that point you can assume that you have the correct collection of words. I wouldn't consider it to be very effective though due to differences in browser rendering, font size, etc however it might be able to get the job done. I don't have time to build a POC. Your title question simply isn't possible because document.querySelector only returns elements
.

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter: `window.getComputedStyle()` only lets you query element and pseudo-element *styles*. The reason you are able to obtain the content of the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements is because they use the `content` CSS property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you can't select the pseudo element itself, you could replicate the behavior of `:first-line`, to determine the text. I wrote a quick JS function, similar to the one [@Kevin B suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097389/use-first-line-pseudo-element-as-a-jquery-selector#comment31738510_21097389)s. The function initially determines the height of the element if there is only one line of text present. A `for` loop is then used to remove a word from the text node until the element's new height equals the initial height. The function then returns with the `first-line` text.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/V5pmv/) - the function is run onLoad, therefore if the window's width changes, the text obviously won't match `first-line`. You could easily fix this by running the function when the screen is resized.

JavaScript function - no jQuery

```
function first_line(element) {
    var el = document.getElementById(element), cache = text = el.innerHTML;
    el.innerHTML = 'a'; var initial = el.offsetHeight; el.innerHTML = cache;
    arr = text.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        text = text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf(" "));
        if (el.offsetHeight == initial) {
            var temp = el.innerHTML;
            el.innerHTML = cache;
            return temp;
        }
        el.innerHTML = text;
    }
}
```

I don't know if I'm re-inventing the wheel here, or not; but this does work. I'm not aware of any jQuery or built-in JS that is able to achieve this. Disregarding browser support, this should also work without any cross-browser styling inconsistencies. It *seems* to work with any types of padding/borders. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/w799j/)

Comment: I was quite impressed wit your code here.  So much so, in fact, I re-purposed it as part of my answer here (thought you might like to know): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845450/adding-the-link-that-makes-the-paragraph-collapse-to-the-last-visbile-line-of-th

Answer (score 1):

I guess this Stackoverflow question is what you are looking for:

[getting the first line of text in an element jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381012/getting-the-first-line-of-text-in-an-element-jquery)

```
var first_line = $("#element")
                       .contents()
                       .filter(function() { 
                           return !!$.trim( this.innerHTML || this.data ); 
                       })
                       .first();
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it exactly. In that example content of the element consists of individual nodes (textnode, span, div etc.) In my case it's just a block of text