# JQuery .on("click") triggers "mouseover" on touch device

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, mouseevent, touch-event

I'm encountering unwanted behavior when using JQuery's `$.on("click", function(){});` on touch devices. This is my code below:

**Code:**

```
$(".team").on("mouseover", teamMouseOver);
$(".team").on("mouseout", teamMouseOut);
$(".team").on("click", teamThumbClicked);

function teamMouseOver(event){
    console.log(event.type);
}

function teamMouseOut(event){
    // Do something
}

function teamThumbClicked(event){
    console.log("Clicked!");
}
```

**Problem:**

With the code above, tapping on a `.team` element on a touch device simultaneously triggers both listeners, giving me the following console log:

```
mouseover
Clicked!
```

**Question**
Why is `mouseover` being triggered on a touch device? This is not the behavior that I would expect from a device that doesn't have a mouse. Is this a bug? What event should I be using so "mouseover" only gets fired when it's an actual mouse pointer that's entering?

My JQuery version is 2.2.4.

Comment: **[This may be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12187105/2065039)**

Comment: This is the correct behavior. What are you trying to achieve? I just recently ran in to the same problem (unwanted classes being added on mobile 'click') and was able to solve the issue using CSS specificity: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: I display a tooltip on `mouseover` and I hide it on `click`. If these two events are triggered simultaneously, the tooltip stays visible, when it should be hidden because you clicked. That's why I don't need `mouseover` to be triggered when the device doesn't have a mouse. I thought that's what `touch` events were for. Did JQuery do this on purpose to simulate :hover effects?

Comment: @MarcoDelValle Did you eventually solve this? I am trying to solve a similar bug. Thanks!

Comment: @unsingefou I don't exactly remember, since it was over a year ago, but I think I disabled the `"mouseover"` event listener if `"touchstart"` happens before `"clicked"`. It's convoluted, but it was the only way I found to allow for devices that had both mouse and touch inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue and this is what I did to solve the problem.

```
$('#myEl').on('click', myElClickEvent);

$('#myEl').on('mouseenter', myElMouseEnterEvent);

function myElClickEvent (event) {
   $(this).addClass('Clicked');
}

function myElMouseEnterEvent() {
    // Turn off events
    $('#myEl').off();

    // After 100 milliseconds cut on events, notice click event won't trigger
    setTimeout(function() {
       // .off() is used to prevent from adding multiple click events if the user hovers multiple elements too quickly.
       $('#myEl').off().on('click', myElClickEvent);             
       $('#myEl').off().on('mouseenter', myElMouseEnterEvent);
    }, 100);


   // Do some mouseenter stuff, whatever the reqs. are.
}
```

This is what I did and it worked fine for my use case. Hopefully this helps someone in the future. The idea is to turn off the click event within the mouse enter event and then after 100 milliseconds cut the mouse click event back on. This will prevent both events from triggering on touch.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and also felt that it was a bit annoying that we cant separate the two events. My approach to solve this was adding the touchend event and let it flag that it is a touch device first. Since the rest of the events will follow, I can ignore them or do something else with them and they still will still be run if triggered by a non touch device.

```
var touchEndDetected = false;
var mouseOverDetected = false;

$('#myEl').on('click mouseover touchend', function (e) {
    console.log('Event type: ' + e.type);

    if(mouseOverDetected) {
        console.log('Mouseover event has already run this before');
        touchEndDetected = false;
        mouseOverDetected = false;
        return;
    }

    if(touchEndDetected) {
        touchEndDetected = false;
        mouseOverDetected = true;
        console.log('Touchend event has already run this before');
        return;
    }

    if(e.type === 'touchend') {
        touchEndDetected = true;
        mouseOverDetected = false;
    }

    console.log('This code will only run once when touch');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `.preventDefault()` on the original touch event.

The API link actually provides the answer.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Supporting_both_TouchEvent_and_MouseEvent#event_firing.

In your case, you are using jQuery's `.on()` function, to which you can send multiple events (separated by spaces), so you can add  `touchstart` or  `ontouchstart` to that string and just call preventDeault() right off the bat in your handler function.

```
$(".team").on("click touchstart", teamThumbClicked);

// and later...

function teamThumbClicked(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent further mouse events from being dispatched
    console.log("Clicked!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The *relatedTarget* property of *MouseEvent* is null when the `mouseenter` or `mouseover` is triggered by click or touch.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget

```js
someElement.addEventListener("mouseover", (e)=>{
  e.relatedTarget // null if triggered by click or touch, 
                  // otherwise it refers to the element the pointer came from.
})
```