# What is the !! operator in javascript?

Tags: javascript, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)
>   [Can someone explain this ‘double negative’ trick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686583/can-someone-explain-this-double-negative-trick)

Because I'm playing around with the HTML5 video possibilities, I came across [getUserMedia.js](https://github.com/addyosmani/getUserMedia.js), which offers cross browser support.

While investigating how the library works (and trying to get it working in a requirejs module), I found the following strange `if` construct:

```
if ( !! navigator.getUserMedia_) {
   ...
```

Double negation? **What does it mean and why?** Why not simple use the following?

```
if (navigator.getUserMedia_) {
   ...
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4686608/1499781

Comment: It's not really useful for an `if` condition but it can be used to convert a value to a boolean value if required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double negation `!!` in JavaScript simply converts values to boolean type.

Comment: But why is it 'better' than the second construct. Since navigator.getUserMedia_ is (or should be) a function, why not use `typeof navigator.getUserMedia_ === 'function'`. My question was not only what it means, but in what cases it should be used.

Comment: @asgoth I can't say that this is "better". For me it is redundant. `!!` simply gives you the explicit `true` or `false` value, whereas condition in `if` clause checks if the value is not falsey (i.e. not `""`, `0`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, or `false`). So in your example we can easily omit the type conversion.

Answer (score 2):

`!!` is usually used for casting variables to boolean (enforcing the boolean context)

That's used because different types can be evaluated to `false`, for example `undefined`, `null`, `''`, etc.

If you use: `!!undefined`, you get:

1. `!!undefined`
2. `!true`
3. `false`

In that way you actually get the boolean value which is equals to the argument if is being evaluated in boolean context.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an operator exactly, it's two of the same (`!`) which basically converts anything into a boolean. In other words, take the double negative of a value.