# difference between if (!!variable), and, if (variable)?

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference (in JS) between using the double negative `!!` and not using it at all?

For example

`if (!!variable){...`   vs. `if (variable){...`

I know there are times where I've gotten a warning using the 2nd method..

When should each be used? and when will each throw a warning in the console? (for variables, objects, arrays etc.)

Thanks!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686583/can-someone-explain-this-double-negative-trick basically it converts it into a boolean  value.

Comment: This is, in fact, a different question. Just because some *answers* to the other question happen to answer this one doesn't make them actually the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference for assigning it, but not for using it in a conditional statement. The reason the `!!` is used is because the first `!` will convert your variable to its truthy evaluation and then `not` it. So "hello" becomes true, is then negated, becomes false, and the second `!` will negate the false, resulting in true. This can be desirable when trying to obtain the thruthy value from a variable. However, there is not much gained by doing it in an if statement.

Comment: awesome thanks! "`when trying to obtain the thruthy value`" is a great way to explain this. thanks! I see this used when checking for existence of things other than variables so that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case, there is no difference. In fact, `!!variable` is wasteful.

However in more general cases, it casts the variable to a boolean. Personally I've only found this useful when debugging, and to learn what values are truthy and falsy.