# How come this way of checking undefined does not work?

Tags: javascript

Can someone take a look at this code? Apparently they are not equivalant.

This was my original code which did not behave as I want to. Basically, what I want is to validate the variable only when it is defined. Ignore the logs. They were for debugging.
**This does not work as expected**

```
let { fullName, email, password } = userInformation;

  if(email){
    console.log("EMAIL IS DEFINED");
    if(!validator.isEmail(email)) {
      errors.email = "Please enter a valid email address";
    }
  }

  if(fullName){
    console.log("FULLNAME IS DEFINED");
    if(validator.isEmpty(fullName)){
      errors.fullName = "Fullname is required";
    }
  }

  if(password){
    console.log("PASSWORD IS DEFINED");
    if(validator.isEmpty(password)){
      errors.password = "Password is required";
    }
  }
```

**This works as expected**. Why is it so?

```
let { fullName, email, password } = userInformation;

  if(!email){
    console.log("EMAIL IS DEFINED");
    if(!validator.isEmail(email)) {
      errors.email = "Please enter a valid email address";
    }
  }

  if(!fullName){
    console.log("FULLNAME IS DEFINED");
    if(validator.isEmpty(fullName)){
      errors.fullName = "Fullname is required";
    }
  }

  if(!password){
    console.log("PASSWORD IS DEFINED");
    if(validator.isEmpty(password)){
      errors.password = "Password is required";
    }
  }
```

Edit: Basically what i want to happen is to run the validations if the variable is **DEFINED**. What's currently is that its not validating unless I do like the second example

Comment: What's the problems you're facing with the first approach?

Comment: It sounds like `fullName, email, password` are **undefined**. Which is why the second "approach" works.

Comment: you know what exclamation mark is used for right? so if it works with it, maybe you can try to log variables just after userInformation line ..

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686583/can-someone-explain-this-double-negative-trick

Comment: @LevarneSobotker is using double negative considered bad practice in javascript?

Comment: The reason why i added that comment above was to establish to you that, when your values are undefined, the if statement will evaluate it as undefined. But if you use the ! (logical not), you now convert that undefined value to a boolean, that is why it works. And that is why we always say if (name && name !== undefined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your checks don't check for `undefined`, they check for *falsiness*. `""` is falsy. So are `0`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course, `false`.

Since `""` is falsy, this doesn't work if `userInformation` has a `fullName` property with the value `""`:

```
if(fullName) {
  console.log("FULLNAME IS DEFINED");
  if(validator.isEmpty(fullName)){
    errors.fullName = "Fullname is required";
  }
}
```

You'll never go into that outer `if`, so you'll never use your validator to check `fullName`.

If you want to bypass your validators if the value is `undefined`, specifically (because the property didn't exist on `userInformation`, or it existed but had the value `undefined`), you need to be specific:

```
if (fullName !== undefined) {
  console.log("FULLNAME IS DEFINED");
  if(validator.isEmpty(fullName)){
    errors.fullName = "Fullname is required";
  }
}
```

If you want to bypass your validators only if `userInformation` *didn't have the property at all* (but keep using the validator if it did have it with the value `undefined`, then you need to check specifically for that:

```
if ("fullName" in userInformation) { // or `if (userInformation.hasOwnProperty("fullName")) {` if you only want an own property
  console.log("FULLNAME IS DEFINED");
  if(validator.isEmpty(fullName)){
    errors.fullName = "Fullname is required";
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry where does `""` come from here? I thought I was destructuring the variables? oh I misread. This makes sense now. Thanks!